# How to slide UITableViewCell in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to implement UITableViewCell what will move itself to right when user tap on it and then slide its finger to right. I need also to track a distance what cell has been moved. Is there any way to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a scrollview. Implementing the delegate of that scrollview (in the cell itself or the view controller), you will know exactly how much the user has scrolled.

Here is an open source control which implements a similar functionality:
https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell

Perhaps it will be of assistance to you.